# Is there a way to clear Relay Modern Environment

Tags: environment, relay, relaymodern

Based on this: https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/e5e07c3f12e5de1be584325498b94ed91a2580ec/docs/Modern-RelayEnvironment.md, is there a way to clear Relay's Environment?